# How to prevent multiple Dialog instance being created so that I can cleanly dismiss()?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have the `Bluetooth` callback that is sometimes triggering twice and makes handling the dialog instance difficult to `dismiss()`.

I am declaring the `Loader` instance in Global

```
LoaderProgress mLConnectdialogLoader = new LoaderProgress(InsoleConnection.this);
```

I trigger the dialog called "Connecting.." for 5 seconds and then dismiss.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    mLConnectdialogLoader.dismiss()
                    }
  },5000);
  mLConnectdialogLoader.show("Connecting...")
```

How to prevent the same instance being called twice so that I can avoid having the hard time in dismissing the dialog.

Comment: You could add a flag, indicating if your dialog is already visible - or use dialog.isShowing(), if your class extends from AlertDialog.

Comment: first of all is it right to trigger the action twice?

Comment: @TharakaNirmana: There is a ble device, we have programmed to connect again if not connected in certain time(millisecond).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!mLConnectdialogLoader.isShowing())
      mLConnectdialogLoader.show("Connecting...")
```

In your DialogLoader class:

```
public boolean isShowing() { return dialog.isShowing(); }
```

Comment: There is no isShowing() method in my plain LoaderProgress class

Comment: dialog.isShowing() is throwing nullpointer exception. Should I do any initialization?

Answer (score 1):

just create a bool and check its status:

```
boolean isShown=false;   

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        mLConnectdialogLoader.dismiss();
                        isShown=false;
                        }
      },5000);

    if(!isShown){
    mLConnectdialogLoader.show("Connecting...");
    isShown= true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if i got the question ,, you can put the "dialog creation coode" in a synchronized method 
Learn More About it 
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html